# How to export a named ColorData into a Microsoft *.PAL format (readable by Origin)?

Tags: export, color

Once, I have made some plots with Mathematica using the `ColorData["RedBlueTones"]`. Now I want to use the some `ColorData` in Origin. The Palette-Editor in Origin isn't very helpful and unfortuneately exporting the `ColorData` from Mathematica directly into the *.pal file-Extension (the only option to load a palette into origin) isn't possible as far as I know. Can anyone give me a hint, how to circumvent that problem or even better how to get any solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you understand the structure of this `.pal` format and can you explain it in your question?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot... Opening such a file with Editor is not readable. I fear this is my problem. But searching the internet didn't provide me with usefull answers.

Comment: @Szabolcs In Origin-Help is mentioned: "You can create new palettes using any external application that writes the palette out in the Microsoft .PAL Format"

Comment: Try this: http://willperone.net/Code/codereadingpal.php or this: http://worms2d.info/Palette_file. I guess you can create this sort of file using `BinaryWrite`.

Comment: `ColorData["RedBlueTones", "BlendArgument"]` might help; this will return the list of colors that *Mathematica* interpolates over for the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

See here, the code with this link works
http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1061777?p_p_auth=jNhF9gaE

Copying from [this answer](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1061777?p_p_auth=jNhF9gaE#_19_message_1061803) by Sander Huisman we have:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
ClearAll[ExportPal]
ExportPal[fnout_String,colors_List]:=Module[{colorout,length,str},colorout=Select[colors,ColorQ];
    If[Length[colorout]>0,
        colorout=List@@@(ColorConvert[#,"RGB"]&/@colorout);
        colorout=Take[#,3]&/@colorout; (* remove alpha channel if present *)
        colorout=Append[0]/@Round[255 colorout];
        length=4+4+4+4+2+2+4Length[colors];
        str=OpenWrite[fnout,BinaryFormat->True];
        BinaryWrite[str,"RIFF"];
        BinaryWrite[str,length,"Integer32"];
        BinaryWrite[str,"PAL "];
        BinaryWrite[str,"data"];
        BinaryWrite[str,4Length[colors]+4,"Integer32"];
        BinaryWrite[str,16^^0300,"Integer16"];
        BinaryWrite[str,Length[colors],"Integer16"];
        BinaryWrite[str,Join@@colorout,"Byte"];
        Close[str]
    ,
        Print["plz check z colors, something wrong! kthxbye!"];
        Abort[]
    ]
]
ExportPal["out.pal",{RGBColor[0.5,0.1,0.8,0.1],Blue,Green,LABColor[0.33,-0.48,-0.54]}]
```

Comment: Link-only answers are not very useful here (even if they are Community links). Please, at the very least, summarize the content of what you're linking to, or (even better) encourage the user there who replied with code to post it here.